# Delivery mails to external MX (Google) with the same domain

Tags: exim, g-suite, google, sa-exim

I have a new instance with HestiaCP (Exim4) and I try to configure the email service with HestiaCP and Google Workspace

I have already configured the rules so that all the sendings are made to Google and Google is in charge of routing the email service

All emails I send to my domain from accounts on the HestiaCP server are delivered OK to Google and HestiaCP

However, the emails that I send from user@mydomain.com (account that exists in HestiaCP) to a Google account, for example google@mydomain.com, are discarded, since the email account is not found within the Exim map

How can I make Exim4 try to deliver outgoing mail to the MX published on the internet and not try to do it directly on the local server?

**HestiaCP account:**

```
exim -bt test01@mydomain.com
test01@mydomain.com
 router = localuser, transport = dovecot_virtual_delivery
```

**Google Account**

```
exim -bt user@mydomain.com
user@mydomain.com is undeliverable: Unrouteable address
```

I need all outgoing shipments from my domain to try to deliver first to the MX published on the internet and not locally (I have the same domain on Google and on my HestiaCP server)

What configuration file in Exim should I edit and with what conditions?

https://support.google.com/a/answer/9228551?hl=en

**I need send mails EXIM to Google Workspace and Google Workspace to EXIM with the same domain**

Comment: *"I have the same domain on Google and on my HestiaCP server"*  - 
That is probably the root of your problem.  To work reliable the `@example.com`  e-mail domain and mailboxes should only live in 1 place.  - Don't name your server `@example.com` but use `some-other-hostname.example.com` and don't configure `example.com` as a local domain